aws s3 android transferUtility upload multiple files
I want to upload multiple photos directly from Android to AWS S3. Is there a way to upload a file other than repeating the transferUtility.upload method?
transferUtility.upload("BUCKET_PATH/${fileName}", file, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)

